# Create folder in Jenkins UI using cURL

Tags: curl, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, directory

I wanted to create a folder for my particular release using curl.

Anyone have tried it ? I used the following command, and that doesn't works for me.

```
curl -X POST http://MyJenkinsURL/createItem?name=TestingFolder --user MyUsername:API token -H Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

If any modifications has to be done for the same command to work or some other commands, please feedback. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

You need to tell jenkins to use the Folder plugins to do that

```
curl -XPOST 'http://jenkins/createItem?name=FolderName&mode=com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.folder.Folder&from=&json={"name":"FolderName","mode":"com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.folder.Folder","from":"","Submit":"OK"}&Submit=OK' --user user.name:YourAPIToken -H "Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
```

[Here are some samples](https://gist.github.com/marshyski/abaa1ccbcee5b15db92c) using jenkins api to manipulate jobs and folders using curl.

Comment: When i use the above command, I am facing the below issue:
                                                                          
Invalid parameter - =com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.folder.Folder
'from' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'json' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'Submit' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

I tried removing and adding the quotes, but still the same issue. Can you provide your inputs ?

Comment: Install de Folder plugin first and use a username and APIToken

Answer (score 1):

Java version

```
Jenkins.instance.createProject(com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.folder.Folder.class, "test-folder")
```

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins 2.346.2

```
export JENKINS_URL="https://jenkins"
export JENKINS_USER=user
export JENKINS_PASSWORD=secret
export JENKINS_FOLDER_NAME=MyFolder

curl \
-H "Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded" \
-I \
-X POST \
--user "${JENKINS_USER}:${JENKINS_PASSWORD}" \
"${JENKINS_URL}/createItem?name=${JENKINS_FOLDER_NAME}&mode=com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.folder.Folder&from=&json="
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried using below command and its work fine

```
curl -s -XPOST $pipeline_url/createItem?name=test -u $username:$password --data-binary @folder.xml -H "Content-Type:text/xml"
```